# Grep to filter one text file with another (Very large files)

Tags: linux, grep, centos, matching

I'll try keep this as simple as I can as I'm not that experienced with grep/linux.

I have a very large .txt file (1.7GB) which is in this format:

```
username:email:IP
```

I have another smaller .txt file (Around 100k lines of text) which only contains:

```
username
```

I want to make an output list which contains usernames (case insensitive) that were found on both the large and smaller .txt files BUT I want them to also have the email and IP which were found on the larger text file.

So my final output will be in this format:

```
username:email:IP
```

But it will only contain usernames that were found in both .txt files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need the `-f` option of `grep`:

```
grep -f smaller.txt large.txt
```

In case you want to make it case insensitive, use `-i`. Note this will make the `grep` way more slow:

```
grep -if smaller.txt large.txt
```

#### Test

Small file:

```
$ cat small 
me
you
him
```

Large file:

```
$ cat large 
a1:aaa@bbb.com:123
me:me@bbb.com:123
a2:aaa@bbb.com:123
YOU:you@bbb.com:123
aaa:aaa@bbb.com:123
```

Matches:

```
$ grep -if small large
me:me@bbb.com:123
YOU:you@bbb.com:123
```

Comment: Thanks fedorqui, But if I wanted to save it as a .txt would I do this: grep -if smaller.txt large.txt > output.txt